# HTTP/1.1 200 OK with SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have installed  SharePoint Server 2010 on our server. The problem is: If I go to the website, where I expect to see the SharePoint site, I get the following message:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>
> Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2012 16:12:19 GMT
>
> Connection: close

Can anybody give me some tips?

Comment: Go to... in a browser?

Comment: Yes, with the browser. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configured a managed path ?

If you deploy your new site collection under a web application with a managed path and there's nothing at the root of the web application (eg : you deployed on `http://fqdn/sites/your-site` and you try to acces `http://fqdn`) you'll get a connection close.

Did you check in IIS if there's a relevant binding for your web application ?